# Why is border collapse and spacing not working when you target only the Table Head (TH) inside a Table?

Tags: html, css

My HTML:

```
<table style="width:100%">

    <tr>
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Last name</th>
        <th>Age</th>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>

    </tr>

</table>
```

My CSS:

```
table, th, td {
margin-top:150px;
margin-bottom:150px;
border:1px solid black;



}   

th, td {
    padding:15px;
}


th {

    text-align:left;
    border-collapse:collapse;


}
```

I want to collapse the borders of the TH only, but it's not working. Border collapse and border spacing aren't working when i target only the TH. I can change the background color and the padding and do other changes to TH only, but border changes seems to not work. Why is that?

Note: Before you tell me how it can be done using other ways, please tell me why THIS way isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Because `border-collapse` is a style rule of the `table` and not of the single cells (`td` or `th`). This means that you set it on the `table` element and all the borders in the table will collapse or separate.

You can mimic the behavior of `border-collapse: separate` only in td by doing something "hacky" like inserting a `div` inside `td`s. Check out the fiddle below:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  padding: 2px;
}

td:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}

td:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}

td > div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><div>Cell 1</div></td>
      <td><div>cell 2</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div>Cell 3</div></td>
      <td><div>Cell 4</div></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

as everybody told you , `border-collapse` is a rule set for the whole `table`, it tells how  cells should be printed at screen side by sides.

A work around could be to fake borders with a `box-shadow`.

inside tds :

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
  border: solid 2px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px;
}

td {
  border: solid transparent;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px;
  padding:3px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> Cell 1 </td>
      <td> Cell 2 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Cell 3 </td>
      <td> Cell 4 </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

outside th

```css
thead {
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

th {
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 -2px, inset 0 -2px, 2px 0, -2px 0, 2px -2px, -2px -2px;
  padding: 2px;
}

td {
  border: solid 2px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> Cell 1 </td>
      <td> Cell 2 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Cell 3 </td>
      <td> Cell 4 </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `border-collapse` property can only be applied to `<table>` elements - not individual rows or cells

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse